# Python Pandas: Changing a Value base on index

Tags: python, pandas

For example, I have the following data frame df

```
     r1     r2  
1    False  10  
2    True   20  
3    True   40
```

I would like to change the value of r2 to become the value of its index to the power of its index if r1 is True

```
pow(index, index)
```

The desired result is

```
      r1     r2  
1    False  10  
2    True   4  
3    True   27
```

I know how to target the cells which the values need to be changed, but I just know how to set them to a constant i.e. 0

```
df.loc[df['r1'] == True, 'r2'] = 0
```

But I don't know how to set it to a function of its index

Thank you for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `pd.DataFrame.mask`

```
df.r2.mask(df.r1, df.index ** df.index, inplace=True)
df

      r1  r2
1  False  10
2   True   4
3   True  27
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `df.r1` to find the index, then index `r2` and reassign.

```
idx = df[df['r1']].index     
df.loc[df['r1'], 'r2'] = idx ** idx

print(df)
      r1  r2
1  False  10
2   True   4
3   True  27
```